# How does this recursive function come to this output?

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

Can someone explain the output for this recursive function? Thank you!

```
function test(a) {
    while (a > 0) {
        a -= 1;
        test(a);
        console.log('after first invocation: ' + a);
    }
}

test(3);​
```

Output:

```
after first invocation: 0
after first invocation: 1
after first invocation: 0
after first invocation: 2
after first invocation: 0
after first invocation: 1
after first invocation: 0
```

Comment: It is long to describe in words. It is faster to use debugger and breakpoints.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything surprising here

Comment: So are you trying to learn how recursion works or is there a specific problem with this code?

Comment: I believe this would be considered "depth first".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the code does 100% what you tell him to do!

```
loop 1 : 
     value of a is 3, is it bigger then 0? Yes!
     3 - 1 = 2 (why not a-- ...) 
     call function test(2)
     is 2 bigger the 0? Yes!
     2 - 1 = 1 
     call function test(1)
     is 1 bigger the 0? Yes!
     1 - 1 = 0 
     call function test(0)
     is 0 bigger then 0 ? NO!
     console.log(('after first invocation: ' + 0)
```

I don't think i have to do it for every output but I think you get the point?